# in the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, the equation $2x = 4$ has the solutions $x = 2$ and $x = 5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

in the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, the equation $2x = 4$ has the solutions $x = 2$ and $x = 5$ under the operation multiplication mod 6. However, this set is not a group under multiplication mod 6.

I understand that 2 mod 6 = 2, but what about the 5? where did it come from?

Also, why this set is not a group?

Comment: $2*5=10\equiv4 \mod 6$. That set forms a group under addition mod 6, but not a group under multiplication mod 6. This is because it includes 0, which has no multiplicative inverse. ($x*0=1$ has no solutions) but some other elements have no inverses either. Try working out which are invertible and which are not.

Answer (score 1):

$2x=4$ has solutions $2$ and $5$ because $2\times2$ and $2\times5$ are borth equal to $4$ modulo $6$.

As for why $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ is not a group under multiplication modulo 6 - well, it is a semigroup with identity, and the identity is $1$ -- but to be a group, you need inverses. Amongst $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, only two elements have multiplicative inverses, they are $1$ and $5$.

Comment: Your multiplicative inverses referring to the Caley table of this set under modulos 6 and multiplication right ?

Comment: Yes. There are other subsets of $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ that form groups, for example $\{0\}$, but taken as a whole, in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ there's only one identity, namely $1$, and only two elements which have multiplicative inverses.